# Tangent and Normal accelerations position estimation

Tags: non-linear-systems, estimation

How can I derive a particle position given it's last known positions (x,y), velocities in it's components (vx, vy), tangential and centripetal (normal) accelerations? (this is the only available data)

[image: Non uniform curvilinear motion model]

I want my model predictions to capture the behavior of tangent accelerations but also to take into account the knowledge of tangential acceleration.

The model I am asking about is available at this paper: "Ocean Vessel Trajectory Estimation and Prediction Based on Extended Kalman Filter". My available information is matrix f(x()), I am dealing with the cases where we don't have data about the vessel so we can't directly apply kalman corrections.

Comment: Is the velocity and acceleration constant?

Comment: Neither the velocity or acceleration are constant.

Comment: In that case, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method.

Comment: Isn't the euler method used for the approximation of functions? I don't know which function to apply the method to, there probably isn't one.
What is being estimated are positions of sea vessels along time.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step you can use a simple method, which is for every small time step $\Delta t$ approximate the acceleration as constant and use $\Delta v=a\Delta t$ for each direction, and then $\Delta x = v\Delta t$.  These equations apply separately for each dimension, so calculate the x and y velocities first and then the resulting changes in position

Comment: But I already have the initial velocities where do I include them? can you please clarify a little bit further for a non physics savy guy?
Also, how do I approximate the acceleration as constant based on the tangencial and normal acceleration?

Comment: Do you mean tangent and normal to the path? And do you want a numerical answer or an analytical one?

Comment: Yes exactly! Not formal but analytical, calculations will be performed at runtime.

Comment: By analytical I mean some bunch of equations that you can put your values in... If that is what you want I think we'll need more detail